# Gelo Location strored in DB with the help of NodeJS and MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I want to store Geo Location in DB using Mongodb and NodeJS

```
message:
         'Cast to Embedded failed for value "[72.591760, 23.014510]" at path "geometry"',
        name: 'CastError',
        stringValue: '"[72.591760, 23.014510]"',
        kind: 'Embedded',
        value: '[72.591760, 23.014510]',
        path: 'geometry',
        reason: [MongooseError] } },
  _message: 'userLocation validation failed',
  name: 'ValidationError' }
```

Answer (score 0):

Store location in this form

```
 "location_point" : {
    "coordinates" : [ 
        -95.712891, 
        37.09024
    ],
    "type" : "Point"
}
```

`-95.712891 - Long`
`37.09024 -Lat`

Comment: // Create Geo Location Schema
const GeoSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    type: {type: String, default: 'Point'},
    coordinates: {type: [Number], index: '2dsphere'}
});

// Create Uer Location Schema
const UserLocationSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  geometry: GeoSchema,
  createdAt: Date,
  updatedAt: Date
});

Comment: Data insert --  newUserLocation: function (req, res) {

    const {name, geometry} = req.body;

    // Create user location data
    const userLocationData = {
      name,
      geometry
    };
    console.log('New User Data', userLocationData);

    UserModel.create(userLocationData).then((userCreateRes) => {
      res.json({status: true, data: userCreateRes, message: 'User location successfully added'})
    }).catch(() => {
      res.json({status: false, message: 'User location data failed!'})
    })
  },

Comment: `const geoSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  location: {
    type: {
      type: String,
      enum: ['Point'],
      required: true
    },
    coordinates: {
      type: [Number],
      required: true
    }
  }
});`

Comment: I'm not familiar with mongoosw. Just try with this schema

Answer (score 0):

```
const userLocationData = {
      name,
      geometry: {
        type: 'Point',
        coordinates: JSON.parse(geometry)
      }
    };
```